# Datatables Layout Problem - Buttons and Dropdowns

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables

This is  my current layout in the below picture.  I have marked the picture up to show how I want to change the layout but can't figure out how.  Everything under the "New Post" button (eg, the buttons, pagination, search, table etc) are all are generated by DATATABLES.  I tried to manipulate the DOM but no success.

Here is the layout I want:

[image: Layout Problem]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#table-mh-admin-blog').DataTable({
    dom: '<Blfr<t>ipl>',
    buttons: [
      'copy', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
    ],
    select: true,
    "order": [
      [4, "asc"]
    ],
    stateSave: true,
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="row ">
  <h1>All Posts </h1>

  <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="https://www.example.net/Blog_admin/blog_create/"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> New Post</a>
  <div>

    <table id="table-mh-admin-blog" class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped table-hover" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Category</th>
          <th>Author</th>
          <th>Title / Post</th>
          <th>Created</th>
          <th>Updated</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Associations and Organizations</td>
          <td>administrator</td>
          <td>
            <p> fffff</p>
            <p>
              fffff</td>
          </p>
          <td>2018-09-21 04:06:27</td>
          <td>
            N/A </td>
          <td style="white-space:nowrap;">
            <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" href="/Blog_admin/blog_update/slug/fffff"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="https://www.example.net/Blog_admin/blog_view_single/fffff"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
            <a href="https://www.example.net/Blog_admin/blog_delete/id/190" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"><i class="fa fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
          </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>24354234234</td>
          <td>administrator</td>
          <td>
            <p> test1</p>
            <p>

              asdasdasdasdasd richard testrtghfghf asdasd


          </td>
          </p>
          <td>2018-09-29 05:37:09</td>
          <td>
            2018-10-08 22:48:30 </td>
          <td style="white-space:nowrap;">
            <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" href="/Blog_admin/blog_update/slug/test1"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="https://www.example.net/Blog_admin/blog_view_single/test1"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
            <a href="https://www.example.net/Blog_admin/blog_delete/id/197" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"><i class="fa fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
          </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>24354234234</td>
          <td>administrator</td>
          <td>
            <p> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>
            <p>
          </td>
          </p>
          <td>2018-10-06 07:12:59</td>
          <td>
            2018-10-08 22:37:32 </td>
          <td style="white-space:nowrap;">
            <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" href="/Blog_admin/blog_update/slug/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="https://www.example.net/Blog_admin/blog_view_single/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
            <a href="https://www.example.net/Blog_admin/blog_delete/id/198" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"><i class="fa fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
          </td>

        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="pagination-links">

  </div>
</div>
<!-- end of row -->
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: can you share your HTML code also

Comment: Thank you for taking a look.  I just uploaded the html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should refer datatable in your html.You missed it.I hope this is what you are looking for.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#table-mh-admin-blog').DataTable({
    dom: '<Blfr<t>ipl>',
    buttons: [
      'copy', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
    ],
    select: true,
    "order": [
      [4, "asc"]
    ],
    stateSave: true,
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<div class="row ">
  <h1>All Posts </h1>

  <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="https://www.example.net/Blog_admin/blog_create/"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> New Post</a>
  <div>

    <table id="table-mh-admin-blog"  width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Category</th>
          <th>Author</th>
          <th>Title / Post</th>
          <th>Created</th>
          <th>Updated</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Associations and Organizations</td>
          <td>administrator</td>
          <td>
            <p> fffff</p>
            <p>
              fffff</td>
          </p>
          <td>2018-09-21 04:06:27</td>
          <td>
            N/A </td>
          <td style="white-space:nowrap;">
            <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" href="/Blog_admin/blog_update/slug/fffff"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="https://www.example.net/Blog_admin/blog_view_single/fffff"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
            <a href="https://www.example.net/Blog_admin/blog_delete/id/190" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"><i class="fa fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
          </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>24354234234</td>
          <td>administrator</td>
          <td>
            <p> test1</p>
            <p>

              asdasdasdasdasd richard testrtghfghf asdasd


          </td>
          </p>
          <td>2018-09-29 05:37:09</td>
          <td>
            2018-10-08 22:48:30 </td>
          <td style="white-space:nowrap;">
            <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" href="/Blog_admin/blog_update/slug/test1"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="https://www.example.net/Blog_admin/blog_view_single/test1"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
            <a href="https://www.example.net/Blog_admin/blog_delete/id/197" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"><i class="fa fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
          </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>24354234234</td>
          <td>administrator</td>
          <td>
            <p> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>
            <p>
          </td>
          </p>
          <td>2018-10-06 07:12:59</td>
          <td>
            2018-10-08 22:37:32 </td>
          <td style="white-space:nowrap;">
            <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" href="/Blog_admin/blog_update/slug/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="https://www.example.net/Blog_admin/blog_view_single/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
            <a href="https://www.example.net/Blog_admin/blog_delete/id/198" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"><i class="fa fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
          </td>

        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="pagination-links">

  </div>
</div>


 
<!-- end of row -->
```

Comment: I added the additional CSS from your answer to my page and it works well!  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Easy and simple way to use `datatable` by using below concept in your question DataTable unable to execute due to missing jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var dataSet = [
    ["Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800"],
    ["Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750"],
    ["Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "2009/01/12", "$86,000"],
    ["Cedric Kelly", "Senior Javascript Developer", "Edinburgh", "6224", "2012/03/29", "$433,060"],
    ["Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "5407", "2008/11/28", "$162,700"],
    ["Brielle Williamson", "Integration Specialist", "New York", "4804", "2012/12/02", "$372,000"],
    ["Herrod Chandler", "Sales Assistant", "San Francisco", "9608", "2012/08/06", "$137,500"],
    ["Rhona Davidson", "Integration Specialist", "Tokyo", "6200", "2010/10/14", "$327,900"],
    ["Colleen Hurst", "Javascript Developer", "San Francisco", "2360", "2009/09/15", "$205,500"],
    ["Sonya Frost", "Software Engineer", "Edinburgh", "1667", "2008/12/13", "$103,600"],
    ["Jena Gaines", "Office Manager", "London", "3814", "2008/12/19", "$90,560"],
    ["Quinn Flynn", "Support Lead", "Edinburgh", "9497", "2013/03/03", "$342,000"],
    ["Charde Marshall", "Regional Director", "San Francisco", "6741", "2008/10/16", "$470,600"],
    ["Haley Kennedy", "Senior Marketing Designer", "London", "3597", "2012/12/18", "$313,500"],
    ["Tatyana Fitzpatrick", "Regional Director", "London", "1965", "2010/03/17", "$385,750"],
    ["Michael Silva", "Marketing Designer", "London", "1581", "2012/11/27", "$198,500"],
    ["Paul Byrd", "Chief Financial Officer (CFO)", "New York", "3059", "2010/06/09", "$725,000"],
    ["Gloria Little", "Systems Administrator", "New York", "1721", "2009/04/10", "$237,500"],
    ["Bradley Greer", "Software Engineer", "London", "2558", "2012/10/13", "$132,000"],
    ["Dai Rios", "Personnel Lead", "Edinburgh", "2290", "2012/09/26", "$217,500"],
    ["Jenette Caldwell", "Development Lead", "New York", "1937", "2011/09/03", "$345,000"],
    ["Yuri Berry", "Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)", "New York", "6154", "2009/06/25", "$675,000"],
    ["Caesar Vance", "Pre-Sales Support", "New York", "8330", "2011/12/12", "$106,450"],
    ["Doris Wilder", "Sales Assistant", "Sidney", "3023", "2010/09/20", "$85,600"],
    ["Angelica Ramos", "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)", "London", "5797", "2009/10/09", "$1,200,000"],
    ["Gavin Joyce", "Developer", "Edinburgh", "8822", "2010/12/22", "$92,575"],
    ["Jennifer Chang", "Regional Director", "Singapore", "9239", "2010/11/14", "$357,650"],
    ["Brenden Wagner", "Software Engineer", "San Francisco", "1314", "2011/06/07", "$206,850"],
    ["Fiona Green", "Chief Operating Officer (COO)", "San Francisco", "2947", "2010/03/11", "$850,000"],
    ["Shou Itou", "Regional Marketing", "Tokyo", "8899", "2011/08/14", "$163,000"],
    ["Michelle House", "Integration Specialist", "Sidney", "2769", "2011/06/02", "$95,400"],
    ["Suki Burks", "Developer", "London", "6832", "2009/10/22", "$114,500"],
    ["Prescott Bartlett", "Technical Author", "London", "3606", "2011/05/07", "$145,000"],
    ["Gavin Cortez", "Team Leader", "San Francisco", "2860", "2008/10/26", "$235,500"],
    ["Martena Mccray", "Post-Sales support", "Edinburgh", "8240", "2011/03/09", "$324,050"],
    ["Unity Butler", "Marketing Designer", "San Francisco", "5384", "2009/12/09", "$85,675"]
  ];

  var columnDefs = [{
    title: "Name"
  }, {
    title: "Position"
  }, {
    title: "Office"
  }, {
    title: "Extn."
  }, {
    title: "Start date"
  }, {
    title: "Salary"
  }];

  var myTable;

  myTable = $('#example').DataTable({
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    data: dataSet,
    columns: columnDefs,
  dom: 'Bfrtip',        // Needs button container
          select: 'single',
          responsive: true,
          altEditor: true,
          // Enable altEditor
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row ">
  <h1>All Posts </h1>

  <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="https://www.example.net/Blog_admin/blog_create/"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> New Post</a>
  <div>

    <div class="container">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="dataTable table table-striped" id="example">

  </table>
</div>
<!-- end of row -->
```